# How to filter the props.children

Tags: react-typescript

I use `props.children` in function component like below which is working fine as in all children renders fine in UI.

```
function Footer(props: FooterProps) {
   return (
     <div>
        {props.children}
    </div>
   );
};
```

However, I need to filter the `props.children` based on some properties of child and put them in different div. There are no errors in console, but child components does not render.

```
function Footer(props: FooterProps) {
   return (
     <div>
        {props.children?.map(child => {
            if (child.align === "right") { //no probs with this condition, code executes as expected.
                <div> // grouping into another div
                    {child}
                </div>
            }
            else {
                { child }
            }
        })}
    </div>
   );
};
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't returning anything in your `map` callback, it's becoming an array of `undefined` which React is designed not to render anything for. If you wrap your two intended values in return statements it should work as intended.

Here's what that would look like:

```
function Footer(props: FooterProps) {
   return (
     <div>
        {props.children?.map(child => {
            if (child.align === "right") { //no probs with this condition, code executes as expected.
                return (
                    <div> // grouping into another div
                        {child}
                    </div>
                );
            }
            else {
                return child;
            }
        })}
    </div>
   );
};
```

I'm not sure if this is really the correct way to do this, generally speaking I'd discourage changing a child directly in this way after receiving it and looking for a more compositional approach, but in the case that you do need to do so, you might should be using the `React.Children.map` method: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap

Comment: Thank you it worked!!! I've a question on this part "changing a child directly in this way". Can you point where exactly the child is changed. I'm just trying to put the child on a right aligned div based on its prop value.

Comment: What I meant by that is that you should try composing the child with the div *before* handing it to the Footer component so that the Footer component doesn't need to make decisions about what needs to change about the child and it can just render them.

Comment: It's not an error or anything, but I'm preferential to not doing anything to my child components once they have been handed off to the parent component.